# Import SCXML into Visio

Tags: visio, scxml

Is it possible to import [SCXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCXML) file into Visio as a "UML Statechart" or other diagram?

If so then how?

Are there some options with newer version(s) than Visio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can see the list of file formats supported for Visio 2013 import [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-insert-AutoCAD-drawings-pictures-and-clip-art-f05e556d-a158-4e16-9bd8-5d45071c9b8c). You may notice that all these file formats specify a visual representation of information, e.g. "draw a box here with this size and these colors".

SCXML does not specify a visual layout. The state chart:

```
<scxml …>
  <state id="a">
    <transition target="b" …/>
  </state>
  <state id="b" />
</scxml>
```

describes a logical flow from `a` to `b`, but does not say whether `b` should be to the right of `a`, or below it, nor their relative sizes, any fonts involved, where to draw the labels for the states, what color the transition line should be, etc.

Your best bet for getting SCXML into Visio is to convert your statechart into [a GraphViz .dot](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) file ([this utility](http://www.findbestopensource.com/product/scxml2dot) may work), use GraphViz to produce a visual layout that you like, saved in [SVG](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) format, and import that into Visio.